Why isn't economics mandatory in the school curricula worldwide?
Throughout most democratic elections/referenda, economics usually plays a big part. An example is the 2014 Scottish independence referendum, where a difference of 500 GBP one way or the other at the personal level is more than enough to swing the result.
Given that, it seems logical to require schools to teach economics. Some idea of what GDP is, how tariffs work and their expected economic impact, or why government borrowing should increase during recessions seems like it could go a long way.
Why isn't it broadly required across the globe to teach economics at secondary school level?

If you mean in high school, it was mandatory in mine. But then high school altogether might not be mandatory. For sure in places like Afghanistan. FYI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_education has a map. Also, I fail to see connection with 1st para.

"If independence made them £500 better off, 65% of Scots told one poll they'd vote for it." You don't need formal economics education to understand being promised money or some equivalent prize. Aside, I remember a colleague who used to tease phone political callers with "does it come with a microwave"? (That was some decades ago.) And she had a Ph.D.

FWTW, in the US it's mandatory in 22 out of 50 states https://medium.com/@infero/should-economics-be-a-required-course-for-all-high-school-students-72047269f436 Two decades ago in was only in 14 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0272775703001018 Could not easily find some statistics for the EU. This EU/Dutch booklet claims however that "Most secondary education programs teach students a bit of economics, often focused on introductory micro and macroeconomics". https://www.economystudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Economy-Studies-for-Secondary-Education.pdf

One major issue is that economics is not have a universally agreed theory, see https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/why-is-there-no-economics-theory-largely-accepted-or-considered-true?rq=1 . Look at your examples, the expected economic impact a tariff is under discussion every time a tarif is changed. The idea that governments should spend acyclical is called Keynesian economics, which is school of thought that some but not all economics agree with.

"why government borrowing should increase during recessions" ─ assuming you mean the deficit (rate of new borrowing), this was a point of contention in the 2010 UK Prime Ministerial debates between the party leaders at the time, in the midst of the recession following the global financial crisis. Your suggestion would amount to making Gordon Brown's position in those debates the curriculum-mandated correct answer. It may be that a lot of economists agree with him, but if schools are going to teach everybody that one party's position is just objectively wrong, there will be outrage.

That's not to say that you couldn't teach economics in school, but the parts of the subject which are uncontested by any mainstream politicians, are a lot smaller than you might think.

@kaya3 but then you could say the same of the hard sciences. There'll always be some minority that disagrees with the consensus. Besides, economics is already taught as an option, no?

@Allure Can you give me an example of a fact from the hard sciences which is contradicted by a mainstream party's political platform, like the Keynesian prescription was contradicted by the UK Conservative party's platform in the 2010 election? The only one which comes to mind is evolution, but that has been controversial to teach in places where there is political opposition to it, and in some cases has been excluded from the curriculum for political reasons.

If you mean there are scientists who contest some facts of science, then whether or not that is true, it doesn't matter as much as there being politicians who contest those facts. Curricula are ultimately decided by politicians.

@kaya3 well going hand-in-hand with evolution is "the Earth is billions of years old". And I imagine one can say it's a chicken-and-egg problem: presumably the political platform exists because the politicians in question didn't study economics/evolution in school.

Or you could be more cynical, and say that the political platform exists and is viable because the voters didn't study it in school; and it's in some parties' interest to keep it that way. The same motivation can be framed from the other perspective as "schools shouldn't be teaching a political ideology masquerading as science", and that's not even a totally unreasonable framing when we're talking about questions which are active political debates in most election seasons. Put another way, facts need to be broadly accepted by the public, not just experts, to get into the school curriculum.

And yes, that is a chicken-and-egg problem in some sense, but gradual change is still possible.

Some basics of economics could be included in civics. it's hard for me to imagine teaching the entire subject at the high school level, because there are too many prerequisites needed. Of course, that begs the question that civics isn't often required these days.

Schools don't cover economics because it isn't actually important to democracy.  It is easier for the system to manufacture consent if economics is not well-understood by the voters.

germany
For historical reasons, schools are organized by the sixteen states rather than the federal level. A few states have economics as a distinct subject, others make economics part of civics, of a combined economy-and-law class, or a civics-economy-geography class.
There are frequent complaints that students are not taught enough economics, but the same is said of healthy nutrition. Can nutrition remain a small part of biology or does it deserve a separate class? And how about competent social media use? Put it into computer science, or put it into language classes where different media types are traditionally covered? Or make it a distinct subject? For that matter, back a generation ago I had a 30-hour-long first aid course taught at school, that was almost equivalent to one hour in the time table of one academic year.
So yes, economics is taught, no probably not enough for school graduates to make reasonable life choices, but schools cannot each "enough" of everything.

Frame challenge: it is.  It's just not called "economics".
The basic skills that one needs to understand economics are literacy, numeracy, and social science (ie history and geography).  If you have a good understanding of these then you have been taught economics, at a school level.
Of course you won't have been taught economics at a university level. But the point of schools is to teach children the basics.
Schools don't teach "plumbing", but do teach plumbing in the sense that they teach literacy, numeracy and art/design, so they teach the skills that are needed to do plumbing at a school level and allow specialisation post-school. Schools might not teach "Economics".  But this doesn't mean that schools don't teach the skills that you need to understand economics at a school level.

This does not seem correct, since more than half the British public does not know what GDP is: https://www.ft.com/content/c67c0727-f8f4-4f9e-9035-c223c62c8b9e That suggests that they don't actually understand basic economics.

@Allure And I don't know 95% of the terms plumbing uses, but if I just googled it up I could learn and understand the basic meaning and function of things like backwater valves and bleed. I think your issue is about where core learning competencies end and specialist skill/knowledge begins.  The practical value of metrics like GDP in the actual economic policies and developments at local, national, and international scales is a complex bit of specialist knowledge.  Knowing what GDP is and maybe a sentence or two of its simplified meaning is a google away to most anyone (in the UK etc.).

@Allure there is a lot of thing that half the british public forget form school but I am confident that GDP is at least mentionned in geography class

@zibadawatimmy information can be a Google away, but if one has never thought about that information before, it's not especially useful - e.g. you can Google for the meaning of "net interest margin" in a few seconds, but can you use that information to value a bank?

@Bougainville that's a surprise. The geography classes I took in high school taught stuff like what causes rain & volcanic eruptions, geology and what it tells us about climate in the past, and so on.

@Allure that sounds like exclusively physical geography which Wikipedia describes as one of three main branches. GDP would turn up in human geography

@Allure the geography class I took where not limited to topography and weather. we also learn about different country or region and crucially about their economic power if they were more industrial or agricultural or other, their population. you know, geography stuff. and GDP was cover somewhere in the middle

@Allure I'm not sure if you're being pithy, or claiming every secondary school graduate should know what "net interest margins" and "valuing a bank" are?

@AzorAhai-him- no, I'm saying you can know a concept (it takes a few seconds to Google after all) and yet don't know how to use it.

@Allure That was the entire point I was making. There's specialist/expert knowledge, like valuing a bank, and then there's core learning skills. You seem to want "knowing what GDP means" to come hand-in-hand with expert level skills in evaluating economies, and that's just silly. Perhaps your problem is that you think the average person should be a professional economist before hitting college, rather than acknowledging that certain sectors of knowledge are (presently, at least) well beyond any reasonable capacity of the average person to acquire, even when they're incredibly important.

@zibadawatimmy: I would add that the specific baseline can change, especially as the field advances; to use an example I remember from high school, chemistry classes don't need you to just memorize the Bohr model - you were expected to understand that the model changes every so often, and Chemistry 12 dealt with sub shells and energy level models briefly - to point out that the Bohr model was not the end-all be-all of Chemistry. Also, Organic Chemistry model being very different was notable too.

What do you mean by economics?
Like technically that's just the sum total of all production, consumption and exchanges of goods and services that happen within and between countries. So Bookkeeping and statistics should set you up for that and math is usually mandatory. So done?
While if you go beyond that and look at meta-narratives of how things ARE or worse how they SHOULD BE and what means are effective at transfering the IS to the OUGHT state of affairs...
Well that's a mixture of psychology, sociology, logistics, various factors about the human condition, POLITICS and most of them are not fully understood so most conclusions people draw from them are preliminary or even ideologically tainted more than a settled science. It's debateable as to whether they are sciences to begin with given how little they can make use of the scientific method even if they wanted to, given that they aren't really able to run experiments or to repeat them and expect the same results.
Like the moment someone figured out "how the economy works", someone else would try to break it to their benefit. People who have to pay the bill constantly complain how a minimum wage would hurt people rather than help them, is that because they have their own political agenda of not wanting to spend more money on employees without getting more out of them or is that because they actually have a point?
In the end it's a multidimensional game of chess, in that the rules are often pretty simple and math already has you covered, but how a game might actually evolve depends on so many different factors, that it's hard to make any useful long term or often even short term predictions.
So what actually is it that you would want to teach and that isn't taught already?
